# Do you need to Map a Factory for every value in a JSON or can grab only the values I want?

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, serialization

So I am working through this Codelab for Dart & Flutter.
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1

```
class Album {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;

  Album({
    required this.userId,
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
  });

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      userId: json['userId'],
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
    );
  }
}
```

If I only want the userId, could I simply omit it?

Can I pick & choose which fields / values I want to get from jsonplaceholder?

Comment: yes, you can create a modal of your own choice from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can ignore values within the `json` argument. Keep in mind that if you want to ignore `title` for example, the class still has a `title` field. You would have to account for this in some way. You could remove the `title` field from the class entirely, or perhaps change the field to be nullable.

Comment: Excellent. I have a much larger JSON that I need to read, but I only need a couple values/fields from it. I should be able to just grab the few I want?

Comment: Yes, ignore as many fields as you want to / need to.

Comment: A good practice is to create a specific method to do this. Leave the toJson represents your model, but make another function inside or outside (better) your model class to create the custom JSON.

Comment: @DanielFarina Ok, I will explore this idea. Thank you.